# Python: Mean Value function, raise exceptions when list is empty and argument not a list

Tags: exception, typeerror, mean

I need help with the following problem:
Write a function mean_value(xs) that gives the average value of a list. If the argument is not a list raise a TypeError exception, if the argument is an empty list raise a ValueError exception.

I did the following but it seems to be wrong:

```
def mean_value(xs):
    if not xs:
        raise ValueError('empty list')
    if not isinstance(xs, ( list, tuple)):
        raise TypeError('wrong argument')
    sum=0
    for n in xs:
        sum=sum+n
    return (float(sum)/len(xs))
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.3 work perfectly
I don't understand what do you expect??
Both cases of exception prints the message and 
average works...
Tried:

```
mean_value(445)
```

got :

```
TypeError: wrong argument
```

also with a empty list:

```
ValueError: empty list
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your quick replies.
As another user answered (but his answer seems to have been deleted), one of the proper ways to do it would be:

```
def mean_value(xs):
if not isinstance(xs, ( list, tuple)):
    raise TypeError('wrong argument')
if len(xs) == 0:
    raise ValueError('empty list')
sum=0
for n in xs:
    sum=sum+n
return (float(sum)/len(xs))
```

Using 'len(xs)==0' instead of 'if not xs'. Also the correct "checking" order is to check if the argument is a list and then check if it isn't empty, and not the other way around.